# Add multiple attributes to an existing js object

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I want to add multiple attributes to an existing object with existing attributes. Is there a more concise way than one line per new attribute?

```
myObject.name = 'don';
myObject.gender = 'male';
```

Everything on MDN shows how to do new objects with bracket notation, but not existing objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: You could make a function that receives your object and an object with the new props/values, and enumerates the new object, updating the old one. That'll be a little more concise. `update(obj, {name:"don", gender:"male"})`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

```
var obj2 = {name: 'don', gender: 'male'};
for (var attrname in myobject) { myobject[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
```

EDIT

To be a bit clearer about how you could extend Object to use this function:

```
//Extend the protype so you can make calls on the instance
Object.prototype.merge = function(obj2) {
    for (var attrname in obj2) {
        this[attrname] = obj2[attrname];
    }
    //Returning this is optional and certainly up to your implementation.  
    //It allows for nice method chaining.
    return this;
};
//Append to the object constructor function so you can only make static calls
Object.merge2 = function(obj1, obj2) {
    for (var attrname in obj2) {
        obj1[attrname] = obj2[attrname];
    }
    //Returning obj1 is optional and certainly up to your implementation
    return obj1;
};
```

Usage:

```
var myObject1 = { One: "One" };
myObject1.merge({ Two: "Two" }).merge({ Three: "Three" });
//myObject1 is { One: "One", Two: "Two", Three: "Three", merge: function }


var myObject2 = Object.merge2({ One: "One" }, { Two: "Two" });
Object.merge2(myObject2, { Three: "Three" });
//myObject2 is { One: "One", Two: "Two", Three: "Three" }
```

Note: You certainly could implement a flexible merge conflict strategy depending on your needs.

Comment: good answer but it's a hack and ES6/ ES2015 has a better option mentioned bellow.

Answer (score 52):

In ES6/ ES2015 you can use the Object.assign method

```js
let obj = {key1: true};
console.log('old obj: ', obj);
let newObj = {key2: false, key3: false};

Object.assign(obj, newObj);
console.log('modified obj: ', obj);
```

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure if that's helpful, but there is a trick using JS ES6 spread syntax:

```
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
obj = {...obj, b: 3, c: 4};
console.log(obj); // {a: 1, b: 3, c: 4}
```

You can try to use this somehow... In general, that's a single liner to add or override object properties using js destructuring method.

Edit:
Notice that the placement of `...obj` in the new object is cruicial, as placing it first would allow overriding it with the following params (`b: 3, c: 4` in my example), and placing it last will give priority to the members that are already in the object.

Comment: You can improve your answer by stating that your example uses JavaScript ES6 **Spread Syntax**.

Answer (score 7):

Use jQuery library

```
jQuery.extend(myObject, { name : 'don', gender : 'male' });
```

Comment: Can't use jQuery unfortunately. (Like majorly unfortunate) Although this looks super clean...

Comment: This question isn't tagged [tag:jQuery].

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes I do it like this:

```
var props = {
   name : 'don',
   gender : 'male',
   age : 12,
   other : false
};
for(var p in props) myObject[p] = props[p];
```

Answer (score 3):

In ECMAscript 5 you can make us of [defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties):

```
Object.defineProperties(myobject, {  
  name: {  
    value: 'don' 
  },  
  gender: {  
    value: 'male' 
  }  
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that syntax is pretty verbose, making it even longer than the original that OP is hoping to streamline.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, this has more use when you want to protect against mutation of your objects.
Hehe,I always do that... =P

Comment: I agree. It's a nice feature, just clunky.

Comment: Also worth checking the ECMAScript v5 browser compatibility depending on your target audience - http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/ - in this case nothing below IE9.